# Configuring hcron

Tags: debian, cron

## Initial problem (X)

I have few linux machines running Debian, all of them connected to network. They are hosting webservers that can be accessed locally when no internet is present. Everything works ok, but I'm actively developing whole system and need to push changes. I'm using git and a cron job, so new version is always downloaded and deployed at night. But *who will guard the guards?* I'd like to have similar update mechanism for cron jobs as well. That's why I was seeking cron alternative. And I found **hcron**.

## My current problem (Y)

The thing is - hcron isn't widely used and it's [documentation](https://expl.info/display/HCRON/hcron+Guide) isn't very understandable. I've installed it from .deb package and somehow got it to run.

1. I can see log file being changed from /var/log/hcron/hcron.log
2. I changed config files in /etc/hcron/
3. I've created cron job with hcron-event
   But I have no idea what to do next. How can I add this event to schedule? Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

If you have defined an hcron event file (it should be under `~/.hcron/<fqdn>/events`), you only need to run hcron-reload. hcron-reload creates a snapshot file containing all your hcron events, copies it to a spool directory for hcron-scheduler to look at, and notifies hcron-scheduler that a snapshot is waiting to be loaded. On the minute, hcron-scheduler checks to see if there are any waiting snapshots, and loads them.

As the developer of hcron, I am curious to know what was not understandable in the docs. See the [contact](https://expl.info/display/SITE/Contact#Email) info on the site.

Comment: Thank you, John - you've already helped me here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hcron-users/wZk_UpGJldQ :)